# Centos 6, apache mod_perl configured but not working

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, perl, mod-perl

I just received today my dedi server access, I installed apache:

```
yum install httpd
```

After it, I configured httpd.conf located in /etc/httpd/conf, I modified server name, added server IP, and my email.

Perl was installed already, when I type perl -v I get:

```
This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

I installed mod_perl:

```
yum install mod_perl
```

I edited again /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, and I added:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
Options +ExecCGI
```

to:

```
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    Options +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I uploaded via sFTP a hello world cgi file to /var/www/cgi-bin, when I browse the file I get Internal Server Error. I already gave the file 755 chmod

Hello world file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print("Content-type:text/html\n\nHello World!");
```

URL to test: `http://78.138.126.87/cgi-bin/test.cgi`

Please HELP!

Comment: http://www.centos.org/docs/4/4.5/Reference_Guide/s3-httpd-v2-mig-mod-perl.html

Comment: @user993553 you should submit that as an answer, not just a comment; it looks promising to me.

Comment: it's working now thanks, please submit it as answer to mark it as valid answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://www.centos.org/docs/4/4.5/Reference_Guide/s3-httpd-v2-mig-mod-perl.html

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your configuration it sure looks like you're trying to run your perl script from the perl cgi binary, not mod_perl, which is not what you seem to think it is.

What does your error log say? It would be most helpful if you posted that. I'm betting that ExecCGI is disabled further up the tree.

Comment: Fixed, I added the script Alias in perl.conf, restarted apache, and the test worked